# Tag disambiguation [global-inbox] and [inbox]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, tag-disambiguation

The [global-inbox](/questions/tagged/global-inbox) tag on MSO was based on the [global-inbox tag on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/global-inbox/info), but the wiki and excerpt has not been updated in some time so it has fallen out of sync with the one on MSE.

The excerpt on MSE reads:

> Use for the drop-down global inbox and its functionality; for the notifications themselves, include the [notifications] tag

while on MSO the excerpt reads:

> The global inbox contains information from across the entire network, including hot questions, a list of all sites, an inbox of @responses directed at you, and notifications of badges and ending bounties.

3 days ago a new tag [inbox](/questions/tagged/inbox) was created with a wiki excerpt:

> Use this tag for questions/concerns about the inbox found on Stack Overflow. Don't use this tag for the global inbox that is available on Stack Exchange. User [global-inbox] for that.

Prior to this tag's creation all questions about the drop-down inbox used the [global-inbox](/questions/tagged/global-inbox) tag. I can't find any questions tagged [global-inbox](/questions/tagged/global-inbox) which refer to the ["full inbox"](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) on Stack Exchange (despite what is written in the [inbox](/questions/tagged/inbox) excerpt).

The drop-down inbox contains notifications from all Stack Exchange sites. It's not localised/limited to a specific site like the [responses tab](/users/current?tab=responses) in the user profile is. For this reason, it doesn't really make sense to differentiate the ["full inbox"](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) on Stack Exchange from the drop-down inbox.

Since the [Inbox improvements are live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/1099857) announcement on MSE uses the [global-inbox] tag, should we update the [global-inbox](/questions/tagged/global-inbox) wiki and excerpt to match (mirror) the current version on MSE and remove the [inbox](/questions/tagged/inbox) tag? Or should we leave both tags and create a synonym between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having heard no objections to the removal of the [inbox](/questions/tagged/inbox) (either here or in chat), I've gone ahead and replaced [inbox](/questions/tagged/inbox) with the previously established tag (also used on MSE) [global-inbox](/questions/tagged/global-inbox) on the 4 questions it was used.

I've also updated the [global-inbox](/questions/tagged/global-inbox) wiki and wiki excerpt to reflect the current location of the inbox menu, design, and functionality (mirroring the [info on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/global-inbox/info) for consistency).

If it is decided that a synonym from [inbox](/questions/tagged/inbox) -> [global-inbox](/questions/tagged/global-inbox) is needed, it can be added at a later date.